# Array of structure, strange when printing users older than

Tags: c++, c, printing

This is the code of function which makes me problem:

```
char g2016tmp[10];
int g2016;
printf("Please enter the year for egxample if it is 2016 then you shoul input  2016\n");
char godtmp[10];
gets(godtmp);
int god;
god = atoi(godtmp);
printf("\nI want to print users older than (Enter the number)\n\n");
gets(g2016tmp);
g2016 = atoi(g2016tmp);
int godiste;
int godinarodjenja;
int brojackorisnika = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= brojac; i++)
    {
        godinarodjenja = atoi (niz[i].godiste);
        godiste = god - godinarodjenja;
        if (godiste > g2016)
        {
            brojackorisnika++;
            printf("\nRB:[%d] Name and last name:%s %s Streat:%s %s\n",i, niz[i].ime, niz[i].prezime, niz[i].ulica, niz[i].ulicab);
            printf("Phone:%s City:%s ZIP:%s\n", niz[i].brojtelefona, niz[i].grad, niz[i].postanskibroj);
            printf("Year of birth:%s Sex:%s Ocupation: %s\n", niz[i].godiste, niz[i].pol, niz[i].zanimanje);
            printf("Level of education:%s Wage :%s Employed:%s\n\n", niz[i].stepencc, niz[i].primanja, niz[i].status);
            break;
        }
    }
printf("\nThere are [%d] users\n\n", brojackorisnika);
```

It outputs this:

```
Please enter the year for egxample if it is 2016 then you shoul input  2016
2016

I want to print users older than (Enter the number)

18

RB:[0] Ime i prezime:  Ulica i broj:
Broj telefona: Grad: Postanski broj:
Godiste: Pol: Zanimanje:
StepenSS: Primanja: Status:


There are [1] users

RB:[0] Name and last name:  Streat:  
Phone:  City:  ZIP:  
Year of birth:  Sex:  Ocupation:  
Level of education:  Wage  Employed:  



If you want to go to home page type 1

If you want to end type 2
I am choosing:
```

So this program basically reads one text document and split with strtok input and put it in structure. After that the program should print all users from the same city and it works (I used strcmp) with completely the same for loop with if statement inside and it worked perfectly. It should also print all users from the database, and it works also. But I can't make it work for printing users older than and younger than input.

Comment: `gets` is not standard and should **never ever** be used.

Comment: Please don't beg for an answer. User will see your question and they will eventually answer it on their leisure time. Meanwhile your can read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: The provide source code doesn't compile even with adding `int main()` function. Please read ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).